# git archive inside subdirectory

Tags: git

I am trying to archive my project regardless of my current directory.

Project structure

```
main_folder/
    sub1/
    sub2/
        sub3/
```

If I `cd` to `main_folder/sub2/sub3/` and run `git archive` it archives the contents of my current directory (sub3) only. Is there a way to get the entire contents of the HEAD and project, without having to BE in the project root?

actual git command:

```
git archive -v -o file.zip HEAD
```

Answer (score 6):

Currently, the answer is no. You can use the [`-C <path>` option and argument](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--Cltpathgt):

```
git -C "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)" archive -v --format zip HEAD
    #####################################
```

or cd yourself

```
(cd `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`; git archive -v --format zip HEAD) > file.zip
```

as a workaround.

**git-archive** has a second parameter to specify a path. The only reason why it can't be used to achieve what you ask for is that, in contrast to many other places in git, this path is interpreted as a relative path rather than a [pathspec](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_pathspec), which would recognize `/` and `:(top)` as a repository's root. Maybe they'll add this to git-archive someday.